# How do I unit test failed to upload JSON to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, go, amazon-s3

I have a function like below:

```
func SaveJSONToS3(data map[string]interface{}) error {
    name := fmt.Sprintf("audit_event_-%v.json", time.Now().Format(time.RFC822))
    // Create an S3 session
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String(utils.AWS_REGION), // AWS region
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf(utils.LOG_FAILED_S3_SESSION, err)
    }

    // Create an S3 client
    svc := s3.New(sess)

    // Convert the JSON data to a byte array
    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf(utils.LOG_FAILED_MARSHAL_JSON, err)
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to marshal JSON data: %v", err)
    }

    // Set the S3 bucket and object key
    bucket := utils.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME
    key := name

    // Upload the JSON data to S3
    _, err = svc.PutObject(&s3.PutObjectInput{
        Body:   aws.ReadSeekCloser(bytes.NewReader(jsonData)),
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(key),
    })
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to upload JSON to S3: %v", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

My current unit test is as below:

```
func TestSaveJSONToS3_MarshalError(t *testing.T) {
    // Input
    data := map[string]interface{}{
        "key": make(chan int), // Invalid data that cannot be marshaled
    }

    // Execute the function
    err := SaveJSONToS3(data)

    // Assert the result
    expectedError := fmt.Errorf("failed to marshal JSON data: json: unsupported type: chan int")
    if err == nil || err.Error() != expectedError.Error() {
        t.Errorf("expected error: %v, got: %v", expectedError, err)
    }
}
```

My coverage is missing two lines one for **invalid session** and another for **failed upload to s3** line and I would like to include it in my test, can anyone please suggest how can I do it. As I am creating session inside my function it is becoming hard for me to mock the session in test class and pass it to original function. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Will `svc := s3.New(sess)` work, if `sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{...` fails? If not then you should exit instead of just `log.Printf` the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to deterministically simulate the behaviour of S3, which means you need to remove S3 from the problem and replace it with something that provides the same contract as S3 but which allows you to dictate the behaviour, in order to simulate your desired test scenarios.

i.e. mock/fake/dummy S3

There are many ways to achieve this depending on how sophisticated you want to get/need to be.

1. provide function variables initialised to the desired aws/s3 functions which can be replaced by mock functions in your tests
2. provide an interface which encapsulates the contracts of the individual aws/s3 functions.  Then implement the save function as a method on a struct into which you can inject either a concrete implementation of the function contracts or a mock implementation for your tests as required
3. similarly implement the save function as a method struct which accepts an s3 client abstraction (interface), abstracting away all s3 concerns (which will need to be tested separately); you may then again inject a mock implementation of this s3 client abstraction for the purposes of testing the save function itself

Implementation of these approaches is left as an exercise.